# Nonempty intersection of cosets of finite index subgroups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $H_1,\dots,H_{n+2}$ be cosets of finite index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and suppose for all $i=1,\dots,n+2$, $\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ is nonempty. Is it then true that $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n+2}H_j$ is nonempty?

Edit: The question was answered in MO, see the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/457932/172802).

Some comments:

- The statement is true for $n=1$. My proof required using that for any $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}^{>0}$ we have $\text{gcd}(a,\text{lcm}(b,c))=\text{lcm}(\text{gcd}(a,b),\text{gcd}(a,c))$). This is a one-dimensional analogue of what I say I tried below.
- The following statement is false: Let $H_1,\dots,H_{n+1}$ be cosets of finite index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ and suppose for all $i=1,\dots,n+2$, $\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ is nonempty. Then $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n+2}H_i$ is nonempty. Counterexample: For $i=1,\dots,n$ let $H_i=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n;x_i\text{ is even}\}$ and let $H_{n+1}=\{x\in\mathbb{Z}^n;\sum_jx_j\text{ is odd}\}$.
- Something I tried: we can suppose WLOG that $0\in H_1\cap\dots\cap H_{n+1}$, so that $H_1,\dots,H_{n+1}$ are subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, and $H_{n+2}=p+V$, for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ and some finite index subgroup $V$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$. Then we know that, for all $i=1,\dots,n+1$, the fact that $\bigcap_{j\neq i}H_j$ is nonempty means that

$$p\in V+\bigcap_{j\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}\setminus\{i\}}H_j.$$
That is, for all $i=1,\dots,n+1$, $p$ can be expressed as $v_i+x_i$, where $v_i\in V$ and $x_i\in\bigcap_{j\in\{1,\dots,n+1\}\setminus\{i\}}H_j$.

It would be enough to prove that this implies
$$p\in V+\bigcap_{j=1,\dots,n+1}H_j,$$
which is equivalent to $\bigcap_{j=1}^{n+2}H_j$ being nonempty.

Comment: Cross-posted (something you should not do without waiting for a week or so): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457901/nonempty-intersection-of-cosets-of-finite-index-subgroups